# iMessages Not In Sync

Tags: iphone, ipad, mac, ipod-touch, messages

My iPod, iPad, and Mac are all used for sending iMessages. However, when I send a message from one device and have a conversation with someone else, the sent and received messages don't usually appear on the other devices. This makes for strange breaks in the conversation thread when switching between devices. What could be a reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just yesterday, Brian X Chen posted a [similar problem](http://gadgetwise.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/05/14/imessage-fix/). The solution he suggested is to uninstall Messages Beta on your Mac.

Comment: I think this is more about how often your have iMessages open. I have iMessages open constantly so there is really very little cached messages to sync. As a result i have never seen this issue. I have had associates who have not opened iMessages for a couple of weeks and experience the issues you have reported.