# iMessage sync with computer after deleting

Tags: data-synchronization, messages, macos

If you send a text on your iphone and then immediately delete it while the synced Mac computer and ipad is off/not connected to Wifi, will the messages still appear in chat on the Mac when you connect it?

Comment: Let us know if http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76534/ or http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68664 or http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51347 doesn't cover your question sufficiently.

Answer (score 0):

> When the iMessage is send, then its sent.

So when you activate iMessage again on this other "Computer" (Mac, iPad, iPhone), then it appears. It could be that after a certain amount of days, the message is deleted from Apples Server.